# SSH connections slow for certain server versions

Tags: ssh

It takes me about 10 seconds to get a password prompt when connecting to a server on my network. When I connect to another server (eg. GitHub), the response is very fast.

Doing a bit of research, it seems that the usual culprits for a slow server response are reverse DNS and GSSAPI functionality. I've disabled both of these individually on the server, and neither change improved the situation.

```
$ ssh -v <hostname>
<a bunch of stuff about reading configs, connecting and reading key files>
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
<a long wait - 5-10 seconds>
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
<many more messages, get to login very quickly>
```

Connections between two servers using the same OpenSSH 5.3 proceed quickly as well.

Based on the above, I think there is some sort of protocol negotiation happening. Am I understanding this correctly? Can I force a certain protocol for specific clients or servers to speed up the server response time?

Comment: Try increasing the debug level. Also tcpdump may tell you if anything is happening.  May also be tcpwrappers.

Comment: How are you authenticating users, could slow LDAP / NIS / AD user lookups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was not due to SSH, but rather a delay due to tcp_wrappers rule processing. Thanks to @BillThor for the comment that pointed me in the right direction. Using the %u substitution (or a user@host rule) causes tcp wrappers to attempt an IDENT/auth request to the client machine to try to get the user name of the person connecting. In my case, there was no server on the client, so tcp wrappers waited for the request to timeout before continuing to allow the connection.

I figured out that the problem was not with SSH while trying to get more detail about what happened on the server side.

First, I logged in to the server using `ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 <hostname>`. This creates a tunnel over the SSH connection which forwards port 8080 on my machine to 8080 on the server.

Next, I started a second SSH server in debug mode, listening on port 8080: `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 8080`. When logging in to my debug server, everything was nice and fast!

Answer (score -1):

As you state, usually this kind of error are due to DNS lookup and GSSAPI functionality.

Having faced the same issue in the past, I would recommand to check the syntax to disable these features as the syntax could change from one OS to another one.

As sample, *LookupClientHostnames=no* is for some Solaris version.
Also having entries in */etc/hosts* could help.

Comment: The OP clearly stated he already disabled these.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a suggestion. I am sure that I had the syntax correct, as I was simply commenting and/or modifying lines in the distro-provided /etc/ssh/sshd.config.